# Minimum subarray difference in python

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider I have a non-empty array of integers: `A0..An`. And consider a parameter `P where 0 < P <=n`. I need to find a minimum absolute difference between left and right subarray splited by P. For example:

```
  A[0] = 3
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 2
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 3

P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7 
P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5 
P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1 
P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

The solution in this case is `1`

I finished with the code below:

```
def solution(A):
    lsum, rsum = A[0], sum(A[1:])
    diff = abs(rsum - lsum)
    p = 1
    while True:
        lsum += A[p]
        rsum -= A[p]
        next = abs(rsum - lsum)
        if next < diff:
            diff = next
            p += 1
        else:
            return diff
```

but I my solution has some bugs. It works in some cases but return wrong answer in some conditions. For example: in condition like `large sequence, numbers from -1 to 1, length = ~100,000` it returns the wrong answer

P.S.: I finished with solution below:

```
 def solution(lst):
    lsum, rsum = lst[0], sum(lst[1:])
    diff = abs(lsum - rsum)
    for i in xrange(1, len(lst) - 1):
        lsum += lst[i]
        rsum -= lst[i]
        ndiff = abs(lsum - rsum)
        diff = min(diff, ndiff)
    return diff
```

Comment: You are searching for `P`, not the `difference`? That wasn't 100% clear for me from the question.

Comment: @NiklasR: I agree, the question is not very well phrased. Still, he is looking for the difference and not for P. He says the solution is `1`. If `P` was what he cared about, the solution would have been 3.

Comment: Complexity is exactly `O(n)`, why do you want a better solution? Or what kind of 'better'?

Comment: Btw. `abs()` is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: better in what sence? Probably a python purist can do this in one line.. But I'm pretty sure you can't do it better than in O(n).

Comment: I think your code have question: if the difference list is [1, 2, 0], your code will return 1 rather 0.

Comment: @chyooCHENG so how exactly do you split the array to get 0?

Comment: @dingalapadum I just take a sample, the difference list may be [2, 4,  1], your code will return 2 rather 1. It just be that when you code reach 4, it return.

Comment: @chyooCHENG oh. I think I know what you mean. but I'm not quite sure... anyway, it's not my code. And still in [1,2,0] the solution *is" 1.

Comment: does your current solution work or does it return as soon as the difference is higher than the previous one?

Comment: You program will fail when there are negative integer, just replace the last line with `p += 1`

Comment: check my solution, it's fast and simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bug is this:

```
if next < diff:
    diff = next
    p += 1
else:
    return diff
```

You terminate if `next` is not improving on `diff`. This is wrong, since you still might find a better solution later on.

Other than that, I think your idea goes in the right direction. What you should do to fix your bug is go through the whole array unconditionally and just return `diff`in the end.
Like so:

```
def solution(A):
    lsum, rsum = A[0], sum(A[1:])
    diff = abs(rsum - lsum)
    p = 1
    while p < (len(A)-1):
        lsum += A[p]
        rsum -= A[p]
        next = abs(rsum - lsum)
        if next < diff:
            diff = next
        p += 1
    return diff
```

(Note: I tried to modify as little as possible, i.e. to stay as close to your code as possible. Also, I did not really test this. But I hope you get the idea.)

Comment: There is a bug. It doesn't work for an array of two elements

Comment: @kharandziuk I wrote that I didn't test and it just is to give an idea.. I can fix it later, when I am at a pc. But if you found it, can't you fix it? I was rly just pointing out the bug which I just saw while reading your code...

Comment: @kharandziuk Hey. I'm at a pc now and I tested a few small examples with 2 elements in the array. [1,4] => 3, [5,2] => 3, [5, -2] => 3. The last one suggest that the complete array is taken vs an empty one. Is this one the one which you mean is wrong? should both arrays be non-empty?

Comment: @kharandziuk: Oh, I just saw from your solution, that you probably want  both arrays to be non-empty. I adjusted my code to comply with yours. (Edit: btw. thx for accepting my answer although it still contained a bug). Hopefully it is fine now...;)

Answer (score 5):

This is more concise yet still O(n):

```
import itertools

def min_diff(A):
    total = sum(A)
    return min(abs(total - lsum - lsum) for lsum in itertools.accumulate(A))
```

[`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) is available from Python 3.2 up.

Comment: love itertools! `accumulate()` is python3 only though.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (the previous solution had a high complexity, my bad)

This is a remake of yours, but getting rid of the indexing on the list
and using the `min` built-in function to get the minimum.

```
def solution(a):
    lsum = a[0]
    rsum = sum(a)-lsum
    dfs = [abs(rsum-lsum),]
    for el in a[1:]:
        lsum+=el
        rsum-=el
        dfs.append(abs(rsum-lsum))
    return min(dfs)
```

calling it with

```
sol = solution([3,1,2,4,3])
print(sol)
```

produces

```
1
```

Comment: I guess complexity in such case O(n^2)

Comment: It seems slower, `O(n^2)`