# Divide an array into k partitions subarray that have minimum difference

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, partition

I have a problem: given an array a1..aN a non negative K, `(K<N)`. Divide the array into K partitions subarray that have minimum difference. After that, list the optimize subarray found.
For example: 
Input: `a=[1,2,3,4,7], K=3`
Output: `{1,4}, {2,3}, {7}`
Explain: `1+4=5, 2+3=5, 7=7` => difference=2 is min => chose

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33276923/minimum-subarray-difference-in-python

Comment: Thank you but this not solve my problem. In my problem, subarrays have elements not contiguous and number of elements in is not constant, as long as the difference between max and min sum of list subarrays is min difference. (for my example: min:5, max:7 => difference=2 is min optimize)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal solution to the problem you've stated is NP-hard, but here's a simple naive approach that does fairly well for many cases:

```
def naive_partition(a, k):
    result = [[] for _ in range(k)]
    sums = [0] * k
    for x in sorted(a, reverse=True):
        i = sums.index(min(sums))
        sums[i] += x
        result[i].append(x)

    return result


print(naive_partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 7], 3))
```

Result:

```
[[7], [4, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it work pretty quick. I have tried to list all k partitions and find the suitable in these list, but it too slow when I give over 20 elements of array and divide it into 7 partitions.